# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__builtin__' Stylegan XL

Tags: python, pytorch, stylegan

I'm running a modified version of stylegan 3 with the provided conda env on popOS 22.04 that can be found here: https://github.com/autonomousvision/stylegan_xl

When training finishes or resumes I get the following error. I think it has to do with loading the network pickle file but I can't seem to track down the issue.

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/nicholasjprimiano/stylegan_xl/train.py", line 336, in 
main()  # pylint: disable=no-value-for-parameter

File "/home/nicholasjprimiano/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py",
line 1130, in **call**
return self.main(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/nicholasjprimiano/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1055, in main
rv = self.invoke(ctx)

File "/home/nicholasjprimiano/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1404, in invoke
return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)

File "/home/nicholasjprimiano/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 760, in invoke
return __callback(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/nicholasjprimiano/stylegan_xl/train.py", line 321, in main
launch_training(c=c, desc=desc, outdir=opts.outdir, dry_run=opts.dry_run)

File "/home/nicholasjprimiano/stylegan_xl/train.py", line 104, in launch_training
subprocess_fn(rank=0, c=c, temp_dir=temp_dir)

File "/home/nicholasjprimiano/stylegan_xl/train.py", line 49, in subprocess_fn
training_loop.training_loop(rank=rank, **c)

File "/home/nicholasjprimiano/stylegan_xl/training/training_loop.py", line 186, in training_loop
resume_data = legacy.load_network_pkl(f)

File "/home/nicholasjprimiano/stylegan_xl/legacy.py", line 27, in load_network_pkl
data = _LegacyUnpickler(f).load()

File "/home/nicholasjprimiano/stylegan_xl/legacy.py", line 78, in find_class
return super().find_class(module, name)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '**builtin**'

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this error come when you have two or more version of python in your system.

Keep only one python and remove the rest.